# How to debug an "undefined" value in JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

**form.html**

```js
function validate() {
  var name = document.Myform.name.value;
  document.write(name);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="validations.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="Myform" onsubmit="return validate()">
    Enter name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Output: undefined
After typing my name in input box it is showing undefined.

Comment: make use of id insted of name ...

Comment: name="name" instead of name=="name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is on your input. you should change t he name=="name" to name="name". Then change your validate function to us getElementsByName. See the code below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function validate(){ 
  var name=document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
  document.write(name);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Myform"  onsubmit="return validate()">
Enter name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to fix your `name=="name"`. In HTML we use `=` to assign attribute values/

```js
function validate() {
  var name = document.Myform.name.value;
  document.write(name);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="validations.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="Myform" onsubmit="return validate()">
    Enter name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

dont make use of `name` attribute it old way of W3C standard, from long time they are suggesting make use of `id` attribute.

you code needs to be like this

```
<input type="text" id="txtname"/><br><br>
```

and javascript like

```
var name=document.getElementById("txtname").value;
```

Comment: Name has a different meaning than id. Each has its own functionality. I agree that referencing an element can better be done through an id. However(!), both solutions work (as long as the id's and names are unique on the page).

Comment: @JoostS - agree with you but for this id is best fit

Answer (score 0):

the `validate` function doesn't return anything as would usually be the case for this type of event hander ~ it will instead simply write the name ~ is that the desired result?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form validation</title>
        <script src="validations.js"></script>
        <script>
            function validate(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var name=e.target.querySelector('input[ name="name" ]').value;
                document.write( name );
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Myform"  onsubmit="return validate(event)">
            Enter name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```